# edit view without modifying file cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

View(edit) is displaying all the fields correctly and updating modified fields but it cant handle files. i.e.,  if  new file is uploaded then it has to be updated if not old file name has to be retained.

controller:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Student->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->Student->id = $id;
        if ($this->Student->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }
    }
```

View:

```
<h1>Edit student record</h1>
<?php   
    echo $this->Form->create('Student',array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('current_address');
    echo 'resume'.$this->Form->file('resume');
    echo $this->Form->input ('comments');
    echo 'photo'.$this->Form->file('photo'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    //echo $this->Form->input('resume', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    //echo $this->Form->input('photo', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
```

Can someone suggest me how to handle the upload thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check resume, photo fields. If it's empty, unset variable. If not empty - upload and move to your destination:

```
if (empty($this->request->data['Student']['resume']['name'])) {
    unset($this->request->data['Student']['resume']);
} else {
    $resume = $this->request->data['Student']['resume'];
    move_uploaded_file($resume['tmp_name'], 'newPath/' . $resume['name']);
    $this->request->data['Student']['resume'] = $resume['name'];
}

if (empty($this->request->data['Student']['photo']['name'])) {
    unset($this->request->data['Student']['photo']);
} else {
    $photo = $this->request->data['Student']['photo'];
    move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'], 'newPath/' . $photo['name']);
    $this->request->data['Student']['photo'] = $photo['name'];
}
```

Comment: yeah simple thought which I failed to write down myself. thanks bro :)